# jquery content not displaying in html table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

In my php page, I'm querying a database table and the results are shown in an html table format.
One field of the database table contains `<script>` codes and commented lines along with other code. For eg:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
    <!-- STORES html -->

<!-- Start:  Code -->
<script type="text/javascript">
console.log("testing");

if ( $.inArray( 'apple', ["apple", "orange", "grapes"]) > -1 ) { // fruits
 console.log("found");
} // fruits
</script>
<!-- End: -->
  </td>
  <td>row2</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

The data for the `<td>` which contains jquery content is not getting displayed. I've added the code in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9rz52tqa/).

Can anyone help me to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's no code here which would write anything into the td. It just logs a value to the console. Should it output "found" into the td? You didn't really make clear what the precise expectation was. BTW you don't need to embed script literally into the element where the output should appear. Instead you select the element from the DOM, it becomes a JS object and then you manipulate it. If you add content to the object in the correct way, that is then reflected on screen. Any half-decent Javascript tutorial will show you what to do.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rt19htf3/ - load jQuery too

Comment: Just logs in your code.

Comment: Yeah. What exactly is it that you want displaying in the table cell? The code itself? the results the if statement? the "found"?

Comment: Do you want to print `fruits` within that `TD`?

Comment: I want to display the entire content of `<td>` ie, the jquery code inside the `<td>` along with comments.

Comment: @Jenz use htmlencode to display the code. updating my answer in a moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to *display* the code, rather than execute it, then you need to HTML-encode it. Whatever language (PHP or JS, I guess) you're using to fetch the content and display it on the page will provide a function to do it. Essentially this involves replacing `<` with `&lt;` and `>` with `&gt;`.

The end result should be like this:

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      &lt;!-- STORES html --&gt; &lt;!-- Start: Code --&gt; &lt;script type="text/javascript"&gt; console.log("testing"); if ( $.inArray( 'apple', ["apple", "orange", "grapes"]) > -1 ) { // fruits console.log("found"); } // fruits &lt;/script&gt; &lt;!-- End:
      --&gt;
    </td>
    <td>row2</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `htmlentities()` function in `PHP` page

Use:

```
$myCode = "" //Your code from the database will be stored in this variable
echo htmlentities($myCode); //outputs the code on page instead of executing it
```

Link: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_htmlentities.asp

Comment: Can't change the content inside `<td>` as its coming from database.